# where to find _M_key_compare function definition in stl set class?

Tags: c++, stl, set

In _Rb_tree class (in stl_tree.h) , a declaration is like `_Compare _M_key_compare`, where *_Compare* is a template parameter. But later in the class *_M_key_compare* is used as a function. `_M_key_compare(A,B)`. I could not find the function definition. Where should I look for this function definition? I looked into *stl_set.h* and *stl_tree.h*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_M_key_compare` is default constructed if you don't pass it in your container's constructor, normally the type is [`std::less`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/), i.e. a functor type. It may also be a function pointer, the technical requirement being that the object is callable with two parameters and returns a `bool`-like.

For a functor like `std::less` this means that there is an implementation of `bool operator() (T a, T b)` or something similar in the class.